# Read.zoo for reading CSV files with time series data

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file which contains a column of data in the following format `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`. From reading on this site I believe the best solution is to use the `read.zoo()` function.

I installed the `zoo` package from the CRAN repository and load the `zoo` package at the start of my script.

When I run the following code I get an

> Error: could not find function "read.zoo"`

```
library(zoo)
DataSampler <- read.zoo("DataSampler.csv", tz = "", header = T, 
    format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Can anyone help me out and tell me why I am getting such an error?

I read the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-read.pdf) regarding the zoo package but there is no reference to what packages and libraries are required.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the package right? The `read.zoo` function is definitively part of the `zoo` package and if the package is loaded you should not get this error. I don't get it if I run your code. Do you get any output when running `library(zoo)`? You can also try `DataSampler <- zoo::read.zoo("DataSampler.csv", tz = "", header = T, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: There must be an issue with installing the package via tools -> install packages as I successfully installed zoo using this method but when I ran `library(zoo)` I got the following error: `Error in library(zoo) : there is no package called ‘zoo’` When I ran install.packages("zoo") the code works correctly!!!